# Casting function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, function-pointers

Suppose I have two classes, A and B:

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef void (*Handler)( A * a );

    Handler handler;

    void foo() ( handler( this ); }
};

class B : public A
{
};
```

Suppose I have a function

```
void bar( B * b );
```

Can I then go

```
B b;
b.handler = bar;???
```

If I declare `void bar( A * a )` then all is cool, but then I have to cast `a` to a `B*` which is ugly. I can't template a typedef, so is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: There is no nice way of doing this. The argument is not covariant; trying to treat it as such will invariably get ugly, for good reason.

Comment: Sounds like you will have to make use of the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) if you want this kind of polymorphism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution mentioned by cdhowie. You can define an abstract base class:

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractA {
   typedef void (*Handler)( T * a );
   Handler handler;

   void foo() ( handler( (T*) this ); }
};
```

And then implement child classes like this:

```
class A : public AbstractA<A> {
    //...
};

class B : public AbstractA<B> {
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.

You're violating LSP: b.handler() can't be called with any random A*, while the base class promisses it can.

```
B b;
b.handler = bar; // This doesn't compile!
A a2;
b.handler(&a2); // As this would call bar(B*) with an A*
```

It is possible to have a different type in cases like this, but only when arguments are contra-variant and return values co-variant.

Answer (score 0):

This smell like **virtual functions** job.